# Is it possible to use firefox's google search bar directly from command line?

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, command-line

I checked through firefox's supposedly supported command line arguments and found this distinctly lacking, but I can't help but assume it must be somehow possible. Any thoughts on how? Currently running Ubuntu 11.10 if that changes anything.

Comment: What's specific about Firefox's search bar that you can't get from Google directly?

Comment: mostly a possible cli tool since I don't like clicking, but I guess not.

Comment: Well, you can open the Google search page from the command line: `$ firefox https://www.google.com/search?q=google`. But I'm not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: Or you can press Ctrl+K in Firefox to focus the search bar and start typing without having to click it, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I mean, it's close, I was just hoping for direct access.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being obtuse, but what's your actual goal? Is it having access to the list of search engines in the bar?

Comment: essentially yes, I was playing around with the idea of writing some bash scripts interfacing with toolbars in firefox, but also it was mostly a feature which I thought must exist since most form sections in  linux are accessible from the terminal and I was mostly just bothered that this important one wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the [Developer Toolbar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/GCLI), it doesn't look like that has access to the built-in search.  It's mainly for quick access to developer tasks (type `help` to see the full range of what it accesses), not for driving regular browsing tasks.

Answer (score 0):

install googler using terminal in ubuntu
Step-1 : Install git(if not installed)

```
     sudo apt-get install git
```

Step-2:  Change the directory

```
     cd /tmp
```

Step-3: Clone it from link given below using command

```
    git clone https://github.com/jarun/googler.git
```

Step-4: get into googler directory

```
   cd googler
```

Step-5:

```
   sudo make install
```

Step-6:After that move to bash directory

```
   cd auto-completion/bash/
```

Step-7:Finally copy file into etc/bash_completion.d

```
   sudo cp googler-completion.bash /etc/bash_completion.d/
```

Now from terminal open googler

```
   googler your_query
```

For further query refer  [here](https://fossbytes.com/how-to-google-search-in-command-line-using-googler/)

use man googler for more option